# Error in starting admin container during Galaxybase graph database standard deployment

Tags: graph-databases

I'm facing an issue while deploying Galaxybase graph database in the standard edition. Specifically, the admin container fails to start. Unfortunately, I couldn't find detailed information about this specific error in the documentation.Could someone help me understand the root cause behind the failure to start the admin container? Additionally, any suggestions or insights on how to resolve this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the log information for "admin" to see if there is an error indicating that H2 couldn't find a domain name corresponding to the IP during admin startup. The H2 startup for "admin" requires mapping of the hostname and the local IP, otherwise it will result in a failed container startup with a completion operation prompt.

a) Verify the hostname by checking.

b) Edit the "/etc/hosts" file to add the mapping between the local IP and the hostname.